# Regex Match all words in string except for <br> tag

Tags: regex

I want to wrap everything in a string, except for the `<br>` tag, with a `<div>` tag.

So, my input would be something like:

`Hello this <br> is a test<br><br>`, and my output would be

`<span>Hello this </span><br><span> is a test</span><br><br>`

I have regex for matching the 
 tag, but I'm coming up short when trying to reverse it.

`[^(<br ?/?>)]` currently matches every character that is not a <, b, r, or >. Which is just a little problematic, as I don't want to match characters but words that are not 
.

Comment: Split with `<br\s*/?>`, wrap each item with div, join with `<br/>`

Comment: @jhnc Qt regex (I was not aware there were different 'flavors')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Qt but it appears to use the PCRE flavour of regular expressions. (cf. [QRegExp](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html), [QRegularExpression](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html))

PCRE has lookahead and lookbehind operations which allow us to form a solution:

```
((?<=^|<br>)(?:(?!<br>).)+)
```

Test at: https://regex101.com/r/fLVGk7/2/

This says:

1. `( ... )` - create a capture group - may not be required
2. `(?<=^|<br>)` - match must be preceded by start of string or `<br>`
3. `(?: ... )` - grouping (without creating capture group)
4. `(?!<br>).` - any character that is not the start of `<br>`

Notes:

- The combination of 3 and 4 (as `(?:(?!<br>).)+`) matches every substring that doesn't include `<br>`; adding 2 prevents matching, `br><span...`, for example
- `<br>` can be replaced by something more complicated

Limitation:

- usually variable length regex cannot be used in lookbehinds (`(?<=...)`)
- if the desired "non-match" would be variable length (eg. `<br\s*\?>`) it may still be used as long as it has a unique fixed length suffix (eg. `>`); in this case, the regex becomes:

```
((?<=^|SUFFIX)(?:(?!NONMATCH).)+)

(?<=^|>)(?:(?!<br\s*\/?>).)+)
```